# Using Managed class objects in Unmanaged

Tags: c++-cli

I'm including one thirdparty reference to my coding.But when i use it my coding it shows error.

My code:  In  **TagInfo.h**

```
ref class Globals
{ 
public: 
    static DUAL_INOUTLib::DualInOut^ objVM;
};
```

Im using it in my coding as  In **TagInfo.cpp**

```
void CTagController :: ReceiveLivePoints()
{
         float PV,SV,MV,P,I,D;              

    CString name = GetTagName();
    System::String^ TgName  = gcnew String( name);
    double ds;
    **Globals::objVM = gcnew DUAL_INOUTLib::DualInOut; 
    Globals::objVM->Open_InOut("ShareMemory", "FRACT", p);  
    Globals::objVM->Get_real(p, TgName, _T("PV"), ds);**

    PV = float(ds);
}
```

But it shows error in line  Globals::objVM = gcnew DUAL_INOUTLib::DualInOut as

> *An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in FOPStation.exe
>   Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {52762B50-F702-11D2-9EB1-00C04F888C49} failed due to the following error: 8001010d.*

TagInfo.cpp contains more class like, CTagbase,CTagController,CTagIndicator etc.,...I want to use this DualInOut in every class to get values

Answer (score 0):

You should try to find out more about the error. You can google the error code, which comes up with [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/clr/thread/6a973187-79aa-4227-80ec-eda8226f4ede), maybe that helps?